# Is it possible to hit a post route from the back end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a two-stage login feature for a web app using node/express. The post request comes from an HTML form in the front-end, then I want to modify the form data and send it to another post route.

I know that res.redirect(307, '/route') can redirect a post route to another post route... However, I want to modify the data in the request, then send it to another post route. Does anyone know a way to achieve this? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but if it's your own server's route it'll be much easier to refactor the route handler into a separate function and call that directly.

Comment: yes its my own servers route. Ok thanks i'll try that. The only reason I didn't do that initially is because there's some passport authentication that happens that I don't understand that well, So I just wanted to use the initial login function.

Comment: If anyone knows how to do that I'd still like to know.

Comment: Getting to understand the authentication then sounds like what you need. What you are asking is probably more complicated

Comment: Ok fair enough. I'll take your word for it.